# como formatear JSON con javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo un string JSON asi:

```javascript
'{"a":"a","b":"b"}"
```

Pero quiero que quede asi:

```javascript
'{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
}'
```

como lo hago? Estoy usando nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utilizando la función JSON.parse(objeto) puedes convertir un string a un JSON.
si lo que quieres es identarlo (ordenarlo para que se vea bonito) pues dependera de tu editor de codigo, en el caso de VSC puedes buscar lo que son los plugin ESLint,

por ejemplo tengo uno de javascript que con seleccionar todo con ctrl + a y luego presionar shift + alt + f me identa todo tal y como lo pusiste en la imagen.

tambien si quieres generar un string de un json identado puedes usar JSON.stringify pasandole null y \t

```
var myJSON = {a:1,b:2};
JSON.stringify(myJSON,null,'\t')

// response
"{
   "a": 1,
   "b": 2
}"
```

Comment: pero quiero que quede como string

Comment: quieres identarlo?

Comment: no veo la diferencia entre los 2 mas que el orden en el codigo y la coma de mas

Comment: si, pero quiero que se idente con alguna funcion javascript

Comment: tu objetivo es mostrarlo en un campo de texto? se podria saber para que o donde aplicarlo? lo que puedes hacer es agregar " \n " que simboliza el salto de linea

Comment: y "\t" para lo que es tabulacion

Comment: Es para un comando eval de un bot de discord

Comment: listo, modifique mi respuesta, chequea